# query on a date range in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get documents from last 30 days in elastic search but it returns empty.

it is my mapping:

```
PUT /books
{
    "mappings": {
        "impressions": {
            "properties": {

                "booksCreated" : {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis",
                  "index": true

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it is my query:

```
POST /books/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "booksCreated",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "ranges": [
                    { "to": "now" }, 
                    { "from": "now-1M/M" } 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried all possible ways but it returns empty.

but i can query on  *@timestamp* field

the problem is that logstash changes the field type from date to string. my json is :

```
{
    "index":"books",
    "type":"book",
    "body":{
    "impressions":{
    "_source":{
    "enabled":true
    },
    "properties":{
    "BookCreated":"2017-09-18 12:18:39"
    }
    }
  }
 }
```

and my logstash config:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "E:\data2\log\logstash.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        codec => json
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
         strip => ["message"]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "books"
        document_type => "book"         
     }

}
```

i will log the json to a log file and logstash send them to elasticsearch

after adding json the mapping chasnges to this:

```
{
  "Books": {
    "mappings": {
      "Books": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "BookCreated": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "body": {
            "properties": {
              "Books": {
                "properties": {
                  "_source": {
                    "properties": {
                      "enabled": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "properties": {
                    "properties": {
                      "BookCreated": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "index": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it has two BookCreated one isdate and the other is text

Comment: May you please add the entire output of your query? How many documents you have in the collection? Do you need matching documents themselves or the count of documents the date interval in the query?

Comment: May you also provide the output of `GET /books/`?

Comment: i found the problem, bu i can't solve that... i add mapping but when i send documents from log to elastic it will change the type from date to text. it will consider the wrong field.
i will add the json that will be logged and my logstash config file on my question.

Comment: try to put `"dynamic": "strict",` when you put your mapping, since by default the mapping is **dynamic**, which means that mapping may change (check out this [docs page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html)). If you push some document that does not correspond to your mapping, the ES will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `from` and `to` in the same range, like this:

```
POST /books/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "BookCreated",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "ranges": [
                    { 
                      "from": "now-1M/M",
                      "to": "now"
                    } 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: again it returns empty for hits

Comment: Your date field is named `BookCreated` not `booksCreated`. I've updated my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is an issue with your mapping. First of all, make sure the `bookCreated` field is named consistently, both in regards to naming as well as capitalization!

Secondly, I believe the reason you have two bookCreated is because your mapping contains a bookCreated property. Your JSON however contains a nested structure: `body => properties => bookCreated`. Either flatten/transform the book in logstash to the required index structure, or model your index according to your json, which could look something like this?

```
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "body": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "properties": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "bookCreated": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis",
              "index": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Either way, I recommend you to set `"dynamic": "strict"` so you will actually see when you make a mistake in the mapping rather than just new fields being created